# My figures are not at their place

Tags: graphics, positioning

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}        % To use graphics and insert images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % handle french é,è etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/Ralph/Documents/CiSA/MathPaper/}} % Path for the image
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Study of curve formed from a processed quadrilateral}  % Declares the document's title.
\author{ME}      % Declares the author's name.
\date{April 8, 2015}      % Deleting this command produces today's date.
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Processing the square}
The initial shape is a square, to produce a closed curve from the initial shape, we follow a list of procedures that we iterate it infinitely. 

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{iter1}
    \caption{Initial quadrilateral}
\end{figure}

This list of procedure is like so :
On each side of the square, a middle point is drawn M$_{x}$.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{midpoints}
    \caption{Initial quadrilateral}
\end{figure}

Then a point in the middle of every pair of adjacent points (A$_{x}$) is drawn. For example there will be one between M$_1$ and A, one between A and M$_2$, etc.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{newPoints}  
    \caption{Initial quadrilateral}
\end{figure}

A polygon is drawn to link all the (A$_{x}$) and it is processed with the same procedure.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{newPoly}
    \caption{Initial quadrilateral}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Analysis of the curve}
Our first guess was that the infinite process will result in a perfect circle. After doing a few iteration with a simple JavaScript algorithm and the GeoGebra application, we discovered that the shape we get is not a circle.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{iter5}
    \caption{Initial quadrilateral}
\end{figure}

A simple comparison of the length of g (21.55) and h (22.15), two segments linking the center of the figure with a random point on it, confirms that it is not a circle.


\end{document}               % End of document.
```

My images are supposed to appear just after the paragraph describing them (like in my code) but they all appear in order just before the last paragraph (A simple comparison...). What is wrong with my code ? [image: Here's what I get]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! `figure` means *float* and floats are designed to, well, float. LaTeX puts there where it thinks best. If you don't want them to move, don't use a `figure` environment. You can use the `\captionof` command from `caption` or `capt-of` for the captions.

Comment: Please see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) Note also that you are starting new paragraphs between each figure (blank lines), which you probably don't intend since they are only a sentence long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`figure` means ***float*** and floats are designed to, well, float. LaTeX puts there where it thinks best. If you don't want them to move, don't use a `figure` environment. You can use the `\captionof` command from `caption` or `capt-of` for the captions.

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}        % To use graphics and insert images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % handle french é,è etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/Ralph/Documents/CiSA/MathPaper/}} % Path for the image
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Study of curve formed from a processed quadrilateral}  % Declares the document's title.
\author{ME}      % Declares the author's name.
\date{April 8, 2015}      % Deleting this command produces today's date.
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{Introduction}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{Methodology}
  \subsection{Processing the square}
  The initial shape is a square, to produce a closed curve from the initial shape, we follow a list of procedures that we iterate it infinitely.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{iter1}
    \captionof{figure}{Initial quadrilateral}
  \end{center}

  This list of procedure is like so :
  On each side of the square, a middle point is drawn M$_{x}$.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{midpoints}
    \captionof{figure}{Initial quadrilateral}
  \end{center}

  Then a point in the middle of every pair of adjacent points (A$_{x}$) is drawn. For example there will be one between M$_1$ and A, one between A and M$_2$, etc.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{newPoints}
    \captionof{figure}{Initial quadrilateral}
  \end{center}

  A polygon is drawn to link all the (A$_{x}$) and it is processed with the same procedure.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{newPoly}
    \captionof{figure}{Initial quadrilateral}
  \end{center}

  \subsection{Analysis of the curve}
  Our first guess was that the infinite process will result in a perfect circle. After doing a few iteration with a simple JavaScript algorithm and the GeoGebra application, we discovered that the shape we get is not a circle.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{iter5}
    \captionof{figure}{Initial quadrilateral}
  \end{center}

  A simple comparison of the length of g (21.55) and h (22.15), two segments linking the center of the center with a random point on it, confirms that it is not a circle.


\end{document}
```